# create_resources - can't convert String into Hash

Tags: puppet, logstash

I am using the elasticsearch-logstash module from

https://forge.puppetlabs.com/elasticsearch/logstash

this is how my hiera looks like...

```
---
classes:
  - 'profile::logstash'


profile::logstash::conf:
  package_url: "https://download.elasticsearch.org/logstash/logstash/packages/centos/logstash-contrib-1.4.2-1_efd53ef.noarch.rpm"
```

and this is the logstash.pp from profile

```
class profile::logstash {

  $conf   = hiera('profile::logstash::conf',{})


  validate_hash($conf)


  create_resources('logstash',$conf)

}
```

I get this error...

```
Error: can't convert String into Hash at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-2/modules-0/profile/manifests/logstash.pp:10 on node pw-idx-11.local
Wrapped exception:
can't convert String into Hash
Error: can't convert String into Hash at /tmp/vagrant-puppet-2/modules-0/profile/manifests/logstash.pp:10 on node pw-idx-11.local
```

**UPDATE:**

fixed using this....

```
class profile::elasticsearch {

  class { '::elasticsearch':
    version => '1.1.1-1'
  }

  $elasticsearch_configs   = hiera_hash('profile::elasticsearch::instance',{})

  validate_hash($elasticsearch_configs)

  create_resources(elasticsearch::instance,$elasticsearch_configs)

  package { 'java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64':
    ensure => 'installed'
  }

}
```

Comment: kris: did you ever get this hash format figured out?

Comment: @Banjer, yes see the update above....

Answer (score 5):

Your data is not fit for use with `create_resources`, which expects a nested hash.

```
data_identifier:
  resource_title1:
    res1_param1: value
    res1_param2: value
  resource_title2:
    res2_param1: value
    ...
```

Since your data is a flat hash, resources cannot be created from it. You likely need to add a resource title layer.

Comment: I had the same issue as OP; this fixed the issue. Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a complicated way of doing it, what about

```
class profile::logstash($conf = {}) {
  validate_hash($conf)
  create_resources('logstash',$conf)
}
```

assuming in your site.pp you already have

```
hiera_include('classes')
```

See an example at https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/3608/parametrized-classes-with-hiera_includeclasses/

Comment: Yes, but this does not answer the question - should be a comment.